# how do i capture the legend shape in google pie charts using jquery?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, pie-chart

I am new to angularjs,i made a donut pie chart using google charts now i want to change the legend shape because default shape is circle but i needed square.
google chart append all code for pie charts on load when page render in browser ,so how can i capture the element for legend shape  using jquery and change it from circle to square.The element for legend is really down in hierarchy inside the main div so how its possible.

[image] 
my html for pie charts:

```
   <div class="chart-container">
         <div class="chart-title" style="padding-right:7em;">Total Calls</div>
           <div google-chart chart="data"></div>
    </div>
```

you can see in snapshot that how google chart append the pie chart inside my html.Inside svg element there is a g element and that g have some other g elements and first g is for legends.
any guide thanks

Comment: Google API  not allows the user to change the default data points representation(i.e., circle) inside the legend

Comment: Do you have any special use case to represent data series points as a square instead of circle?!

Comment: @codeninja yes i have requirement that it should be square

Comment: @Hassan if this is a customer/manager's requirement that it be square, sometimes you have to have a conversation to explain what little things cost when they aren't as simple as they seem. I understand if your customer/employer really really wants those squares, but this is probably the 3rd or 4th question you've asked with this goal. I'm glad you're getting more specific though.  This is progress. Keep in mind that if you're using angular-google-chart, anytime the data or browser window size changes the chart will be redrawn, so your change will have to take place in an on-ready event handler

Comment: @Balrog30 i have done this with d3 not using now google charts